# Can you explain the Summation?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This is my first riddle, so I hope it is not to easy.

Can you explain what I am calculating here?

> Without N I am following the same creature like Alice
>
> +
>
> Add my short name to my long name and I become a King
>
> +
>
> With ITE I am the weakness of the strongest
>
> =
>
> 64

Comment: Excellent first puzzle

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are calculating

> with the atomic weights of noble gases.
>  Neo (from Matrix) also had to follow a white rabbit, add N to get Neon = 10
>  Ar + Argon = Aragorn = 18
>  Kryptonite is the weakness of Superman, remove -ite for Krypton = 36
>  And finally, 10 + 18 + 36 = 64
>  Element 64 is Gadolin­ium.

Comment: You beat my to it while I was still typing.

Comment: Just barely - maybe by 15 seconds.

Comment: Thats correct, I guess it was to easy, i must think of something harder the next time ;)

Comment: @kl78 No, that's a perfectly good puzzle! Don't make things super obscure just because a couple very smart people figured it out quickly.

Answer (score 9):

You are adding ...

> ... the element numbers of noble gases.

In particular:

> **Neon** (10) without its last **n** gives *Neo*, who, like Alice, follows the White Rabbit in the Matrix.

+

> **Argon** (18) with its chemical symbol **Ar** interspersed gives *Aragorn*, king of Gondor if I have read my Lord of the Rings correctly.

+

> **Krypton** (36) plus **ite** gives *Kryptonite*, a mineral which is Superman's weak spot.